# Use a row as colname

Tags: r

I want to take a row and use it to set the colnames example below

```
df1a = data.frame(Customer = c("A", "a",1:8),  Product = c("B", "b",11:18))
colnames(df1a)<-df1a[2,]
```

Expected output

```
   a  b
1  A  B
2  a  b
3  1 11
4  2 12
5  3 13
6  4 14
7  5 15
8  6 16
9  7 17
10 8 18
```

I think the problem is that `df1a[2,]` is a data frame

Comment: colnames(df1a)<-unlist(df1a[2,])

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: as @akrun noted: `df1a = data.frame(Customer = c("A", "a",1:8),  Product = c("B", "b",11:18), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the names without generating a new data.frame:

```
names(df1a) <- lapply(df1a[2,], as.character)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the columns are `factor` class as by default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in the `data.frame` call.  So, the values that got changed are the integer storage values of the `factor` rather than the acutal values

```
df1a <- data.frame(Customer = c("A", "a",1:8), 
      Product = c("B", "b",11:18), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and then do the assignment

```
names(df1a) <- unlist(df1a[2,])
```

Or as @Ryan mentioned, `unlist` is  not needed

```
names(df1a) <- df1a[2,]
```

Comment: @Ryan You are right.  I think it `unlist` itself while doing the assignment